# noob: Not able to checkout code using Bazaar explorer

Tags: dvcs, bazaar

So i started Bazaar explorer and set my local path to a project folder on desktop. I have an http URL in the format http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/trunk..I tried checking out the code by entering the URL in the Branch Source but I get an error saying "Connection error: while sending OPTIONS /trunk/: attempt failed as cannot connected party failed to respond or host failed to respond. Please help!

Comment: Does it work when you checkout with SVN?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to checkout SVN repository most likely. Something wrong with access to that repository or with bzr-svn plugin. You have to file a bug [here](https://launchpad.net/bzr-svn) and ask your question, and you will have more chanches to get the right answer there than on StackOverflow..